# Running total on Firebase

Tags: validation, firebase, backend

I am wondering how to go about making a running total using Firebase.
I am currently working on a platform that keeps track of user activities and gives them points for completing validated events. I am currently using Firebase for the back end. The reason why I chose Firebase is because of convenience really. I haven't started coding the part that gives points yet but I have the process outlined as followed

1. User validates activity
2. Validator (another user with more authority ) validates that User completed activity.
3. The point value of the completed event is added to the user's total points.

What is bothering me is the third step. Is it possible to do that third step without introducing another piece of backend technology? At present all I'm using to create the activities and users is firebase and the app.

At present I am thinking that I should have the Validator increment the user score however that would mean giving one user direct access to a property of another. Is that considered bad practice? Is there a way to have a Firebase simply add two values or do I have to introduce a third piece of tech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is to create a database directory in the Firebase realtime database that stores the points that will be gained for each activity. When the activity is completed, you get the directory for the user in your Firebase database, get a value for their points, add to the value for the points, and then send the new value back to the database.

This would require giving the admin user access to the other users points, which is bad practice if dealing with private transactions such as credit cards or money (which probably isn't a good idea with Firebase anyway). If you are dealing with something without any actual value it is okay.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. I event thought "Have the Validator add the event to a completedEvents object on the user. Then have the user add up the points." The issue then is that the user app would be writing directly to their points and then nothing would stop them from using the console and just writing in points. The points have "value", they can be exchanged for real world items. I am thinking I should have a server with an api for adding the points. and setting the points variable so it can only be written by the server. How about that?

Comment: Yeah that sounds good. It will be more difficult as you will have to deal with server-side code, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of a bit too enthusiastic about firebaase. I read "back end as a service" as "only service necessary beside front end. That is how beginner tutorials make it seem but every intermediate tutorial looked at today says that the server + frontend (app) + firebase is the most common configuration. So i'll go with it. thanksa again.